# Running Mono C# projects on Mac ... and Winforms

Tags: c#, mono, visual-studio-mac

For the first time I am trying Visual Studio for Mac and I located a tutorial for writing a exe that shows a window with a simple menu.

My two questions are:

How does a user of a Mac get the Mono platform? I can't find instructions for deploying Mono. When I look in my exe folder there is no other files. Just the exe.

Maybe this should be a different question but I could not find any "WinForms" version in Visual Studio for mac. I had to use Gtk2 (I think).

If there is a better place to ask these questions please direct me. Thanks.

Comment: You may look at Xamarin platform (Visual Studio for Mac is new name for Xamarin Studio IDE). WinForms is Windows specific framework

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski So if you use this gk2 does it mean it would run on windows, using its gui designer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is gk2, I heard only bout gtk2 cross-platform toolkit. Compatible platforms for VS for Mac can be found in [Visual Studio 2019 for Mac Platform Targeting and Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2019-compatibility-mac)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Sorry, that is what I meant.

Comment: You came too late to the game. macOS requires 64 bit apps, so Mono WinForms is impossible now (as it is 32 bit only). Use Xamarin.Mac to build a Mac app, or use another cross platform framework, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Comment: @LexLi No really true, there are 64bit Cocoa backends for WinForms, i.e.  `mac-playground` Not that I would do any "new" development in WinForms, but if you "really" need a non-VM-based solution, mac-playground (and others) work

Comment: @LexLi I don't have to use WinForms. I am just trying things out and seeing what C# I can use with Visual Studio for Mac that will compile a GUI type project that might be able to run on Windows too.

Comment: @SushiHangover the 32 bit backend has been "shipped" widely with Mono, while the 64 bit backend has been there but not shipped (I knew its existence a long while ago). Mono/MonoDevelop has been out of good maintenance, so any articles/posts on Mono are rather risky to follow these days.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle then you have several options to explore if you go over my blog post. BTW, make sure you use them with .NET Core, not Mono.

Comment: @LexLi if you have a link to any good resource that is "not risky" and fits the principles of SO to supply then please do. Thanks.

Comment: @LexLi I am confused by Xamarin and Gtk. It seems that what I compiled was fo "Linux" that can be run on Mac. Is Xamarin part of Visual Studio for Mac installer? I must have missed it.

Comment: Can you go over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac first? That gives you some basic tips on how to build a Mac app.

Comment: @LexLi You are confusing what was the Mono Project's Cocoa 64bit backend to what  mac-playground and others are doing. Even de Icaza recently posted on its usage.

Comment: @LexLi I have spent quite a while trying to follow that tutorial and it is very hard. It took me ages to see the "I beams" visually on the drak mode XCode. I could not doub;e click the file to open it in XCODe from VS. I had to right-click and do it. Certain windows like Library and Assistant editor were not visible and I had to find out how to show them. And, I am now on the Assistant Editor window where no files are listed at the top. I am finding this tutorial a complete nightmare to follow with the VS / XCode I have installed. Is there a better one? #confused.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Indeed it is hard to follow, as the author(s) assume you have enough familiarity on Mac native development with Cocoa framework, but in fact how many can have that. Jumping between VS for Mac and Xcode is something Xamarin developers have been used to since old MonoTouch days, but not everyone likes that. Honestly speaking, there is no good enough experience yet to develop user interface on Mac (otherwise, I would have written some apps of my own already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know understand that the best course of action was:

1. Create a Xamarin.Forms multi-platform project.
2. Create a Cocoa Mac OS project.
3. Add a reference to project 1 into project 2.
4. Using Nuget Package Manager download Xamarin.Forms into each project.

Now it is easy to create an application with XAML (similar to WPF).

Visual Studio for Mac creates the multi-platform project (step 1 above) automatically with the Android and iOS platform builds, but not the macOS.

I also see that I don't really need to download Mono as it is all dealt with automatically.

Answer (score -1):

.NET Core does support Mac and Linux. And even though .NET Core now supports Windows Forms. [Windows Forms is only supported on Windows.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-for-windows-desktop/) It's unlikely this will ever change due to Windows Forms dependency on the Windows APIs.

Comment: WinForms on macOS and Linux was achieved by Mono years ago. It is just abandoned at this moment. So "It's unlikely this will ever change due to Windows Forms dependency on the Windows APIs" is not fully true.

Comment: It's precisely true in the scope of my answer. .NET Core is very unlikely to ever support Windows Forms on platforms other than Windows. The Microsoft blog post that I linked says exactly that.

Comment: I guess I could have mentioned that Mono has an semi-functional, 32-bit only implementation that hasn't been updated in a decade and has no designer reliable support. But doesn't seem helpful.